# Omp se comparta mal na chamada da mesma função

Tags: c, paralelismo, openmp

Caros... Eu sou iniciante em Omp (programação paralela em geral) e estou passando pelo seguinte problema, que pode ser que seja óbvio. Então vim pedir ajuda. O chamada é a seguinte

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if(i == 0)
      h[i] = fastContComplete(r, cromo->g, 1);
    else
      h[i] = fastContComplete(s, cromo->g, 0);
  }
```

Se eu remover a chamada do omp o algoritmo funciona super bem. Se eu executar como está, ele retornar as estruturas h[i] de forma "mal calculada". Detalhe, os parâmetros da função fastContComplete são apenas de consulta, eles não são alterados em nenhum momento da execução da fastContComplete. Não consigo entender aonde está o erro ai. Também tentei

```
  #pragma omp parallel private(r, s, cromo)
  {
    i = omp_get_thread_num();
    if(i == 0)
      h[i] = fastContComplete(r, cromo->g, 1);
    else
      h[i] = fastContComplete(s, cromo->g, 0);
  }
```

e se comporta da mesma forma. Alguém sabe explicar o que ta rolando?

Agradeço desde já,
abraços,
Josefran

Comment: Começo por dizer que esse seu `for` não tem muito sentido pois está a individualizar casos específicos do `for`. Na verdade esse seu `for` seria melhor transformado em duas instruções soltas, as que estão escritas no `if`.

Comment: Tentei dessa forma.  No final do texto eu disponibilizei o segundo codigo

Comment: `fastContComplete` não altera nenhuma variável global?